# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

Trying to downgrade our project to Java 1.6 on Glassfish 3.1.2.2. Recently we have a project which running on Glassfish 4.1 and build using Java 1.8. Unfortunately, our site using java 1.6 on Glassfish 3.1.2.2. However we must change our build version. Our Java Web Service running well on Glassfish 4.1 but getting this exception on 3.1.2.2.

```
Info: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM'
Severe: WebModule[/WS_ivi]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yai/ivi/rs/IVIAPIS
    at com.yai.ivi.app.AppConfig.addRestResourceClasses(AppConfig.java:21)
    at com.yai.ivi.app.AppConfig.getClasses(AppConfig.java:16)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder.<init>(DeferredResourceConfig.java:90)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder.<init>(DeferredResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig.getApplication(DeferredResourceConfig.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Warning: StandardWrapperValve[com.yai.ivi.app.AppConfig]: PWC1382: Allocate exception for servlet com.yai.ivi.app.AppConfig
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yai/ivi/rs/IVIAPIS
    at com.yai.ivi.app.AppConfig.addRestResourceClasses(AppConfig.java:21)
    at com.yai.ivi.app.AppConfig.getClasses(AppConfig.java:16)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder.<init>(DeferredResourceConfig.java:90)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder.<init>(DeferredResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig.getApplication(DeferredResourceConfig.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

After read from this log, this tell us no class defined, but our Netbeans compiling well. Here are our AppConfig

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class AppConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(com.yai.ivi.rs.IVIAPIS.class);
    }
}
```

and here are our rest application

```
@GET
@Path("/sampler")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getSampleData() throws Exception {   
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("output", "Hello, i'm ivi!");         
    return outputJsonObj.toString();
}
```

This above exception will show json file only for tester.

```
{"output":"Hello, i'm ivi!"}
```

I've checked that class IVIAPIS is exist on our package.
Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which JAX-RS API JAR file do you use?

Comment: @TobiTiggers How can I check? in modules folder?

Comment: If i read from log, I'm use Jersey: 1.11.1

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons your *AppConfig* servlet can not find the com.yai.ivi.rs.IVIAPIS class. The narrow down the problem I would consider following steps:

- check the generated .war file if it contains *com.yai.ivi.rs.IVIAPIS* (usually in the *dist* folder in your Netbeans project)
- check the location of *com.yai.ivi.rs.IVIAPIS* inside the .war file, if you find it inside the war then it should be in the WEB_INF/lib directory as far as I know.

You might check this answer for more details for the *NoClassDefFoundError* 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/4424646